# Custom filtering on month value only of an entire date field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, ajax

I'm using the plugin Ajax WP Query Search Filter (http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-wp-query-search-filter/) to search some custom posts I've created.

The filter works great on three custom taxonomies, however I also want to include a filter on a date field where the full date is stored.

The filter I'd like is a dropdown containing each month, as such:

- Jan
- Feb
- Mar
- Apr
- May
- ... etc...

This would search the date field on its month value. My question is how do I do this?

- dd/mm/yyyy

I know I can create a Custom Meta Field filter, but how I would get it to search on the month part only?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, are you trying to get the month from a date formatted in dd/mm/yyyy, is it right?

Comment: The actual MySQL data is stored in yyyy/mm/dd format. We're showing the date front-end in dd/mm/yyyy (UK) format, but that doesn't matter really. What we're trying to do is use filter the month value from a dropdown menu, using the Ajax WP Query Search filter plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by creating a Custom Meta Field filter using the following options:

```
-01-::Jan|-02::Feb|-03-::Mar|-04-::Apr|-05-::May|-06-::Jun|-07-::Jul|-08-::Aug|-09-::Sep|-10-::Oct|-11-::Nov|-12-::Dec
```

The "-mm-" in each part matches the month stored in the database. Pretty simple really but this works perfectly.